# How can I release the memory of Mnesia transactions occupied after transaction is done?

Tags: erlang, elixir, mnesia

I am using Mnesia to build a caching system, Encountered a problem:

Every time I use `:mnesia.transaction`, it will bring little memory consumption. Almost 10,000 `:mnesia.transaction` calls will consume 1MB of memory.

After some work, I found that the memory occupied by ets’s table: `mnesia_transient_decision` will continue to increasing. Every call to `:mnesia.transaction` will insert a record into table `mnesia_transient_decision`(call stack: mnesia_tm:execute_outer -> execute_transaction -> apply_fun -> t_commit ->  multi_commit -> mnesia_recover:note_decision), and even if I run `:mnesia_recover.allow_garb` and `:erlang.garbage_collect`, the memory will not decrease. And this table is an unnamed table, i can't delete it by `:ets.delete :mnesia_transient_decision`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

testing code:

```
defmodule TestTransaction do
  alias :mnesia, as: Mnesia
  def init_mnesia do
    Mnesia.start()
    Mnesia.create_table(Person, attributes: [:age, :username], disc_copies: [node()])
  end
  def case_trans_read do
    f = fn ->
      Mnesia.read(Person, 2)
    end
    Mnesia.transaction(f)
  end

  def print_memory_info do
    IO.puts("total: #{:erlang.memory[:total]}, ets: #{:erlang.memory[:ets]}")
  end

  def benchmarking(_, 0), do: nil

  def benchmarking(f, n) do
    apply(TestTransaction, f, [])
    benchmarking(f, n-1)
  end

end

TestTransaction.init_mnesia

TestTransaction.benchmarking :case_trans_read, 10000
```

observer_cli: memory usage of ets table:
[image: memory usage of ets table]

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems like `mnesia_recover:allow_garb` always keeps the 10 latest tables, so that's why it doesn't delete the tables in your case. Not sure what the right solution is, though...

Comment: @legoscia thank you! I rechecked the code and comment, it does show that up to 10 tables are kept, but it does not limit the size of table, so 10 tables may also occupied a lot of memory ... I still want to have a direct way to release this memory, or better not to insert data into this table (but look at the code, it seems that every transaction will insert to table anyway)

Comment: @WincerChan, what is the Mnesia's `dump_log_write_threshold` value being used ?

Comment: @Agus `:mnesia_monitor.get_env(:dump_log_write_threshold)` output is 1000, I tried to change it to 1, this has no effect on the test code. Thank you!